# About generating MIMO FMCW IF Signal and angle detection

Tags: radar, mimo

I want to detect some targets where their range, velocity and angle information can be given before creating the radar cube. Then using IF signal for MIMO FMCW radar I want to construct the radar cube. Applying fft2 I can obtain the range doppler map, however I observe extra targets on the map. This reflects to the CA-CFAR range plot and the angle values are zero.

I think I made a mistake while constructing the radar cube, however I couldn't solve it. I would be very appreciate if someone can help me. The code is below. Many thanks.

''''

% Clear variables, close figures, and clear command window

clear all;

close all;

clc;

% Constants

c = 3e8;                   % Speed of light (m/s)

bw = 150e6;                % Sweep bandwidth (Hz)

tm = 10e-6;                % Sweep time (s)

sweep_slope = bw/tm;       % Sweep slope (Hz/s)

fc = 77e9;                 % Radar frequency (Hz)

lambda = c/fc;             % Wavelength (m)

v_max = lambda/(tm*4);

chirps = 256;               % Number of chirps

samples = 1024; %ceil(tm*fs);     % Number of samples in one chirp

NF = 15;                   % Noise floor (dB)

numCPI = 5;

N = chirps*samples*numCPI; % total # of ADC samples

fs = samples/tm;             % sampling frequency

dt = 1/fs;                   % sampling interval

range_max = fs*c/(2*sweep_slope); % Maximum range

dR = c/(2*bw);             % Range resolution

R = 0:dR:range_max-dR;     % Range axis

t_frame = linspace(0,tm*chirps*numCPI,N); % Time axis for one frame

V = linspace(-v_max, v_max, chirps); % Velocity axis

ang_ax = -90:90; % angle axis

t_onePulse = 0:dt:dt*samples-dt;

% Noise and Interference Parameters

noise_power = 0.01;        % Power of additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN)

interference_power = 0.5;  % Power of interference signal

% Array parameters

num_tx = 2;                % Number of transmit antennas

num_rx = 4;                % Number of receive antennas

d = lambda/2;              % Inter-antenna distance

N_Dopp = chirps; % Length of Doppler FFT

N_range = samples; % Length of range FFT

N_azimuth = num_tx*num_rx;

% Target parameters

num_objects = 2;

ranges = [10, 70];         % Target ranges (m)

velocities = [20, - 90];    % Target velocities (m/s)

angles = [30, -50];        % Target angles (degrees)

phases = [pi/3, pi/4];     % Target phases (radians)

% Path loss model

path_loss = -174 + NF + 10*log10(fs);

td = 2 * ranges / c;                  % Round trip delay for each object (s)

phi0 = 4*pi*fc*ranges/c;              % Initial phase for each object

t = 0;                               % Time

% Mixer output

signal = cell(num_tx, num_rx);

mixed = cell(num_tx, num_rx);

for k = 1:num_tx

```
for l = 1:num_rx

    signal{k, l} = zeros(samples, chirps);
    
    % Generate mixer output

    for i = 1:chirps*numCPI

        t = 0; % Reset time   

        for j = 1:samples
            a = phi0 + (-2*pi*fc*2*velocities.*(i*tm)/c ...    % phase shift

                -2*pi*(2*velocities.*(fc+i*bw)/c + sweep_slope*td)*t);   % frequency

            signal{k, l}(j, i) = sum(0.5*cos(a)); % IF signal for the k-th transmitter and l-th receiver pair

            t = t + 1/fs; % Increment time

        end

    end

    mixed{k, l} = signal{k, l};

end
```

end

%% Post processing - 2-D FFT

RDC = reshape(cat(3,mixed{:}), samples, chirps*numCPI, num_rx*num_tx); % Radar data cube

RDMs = zeros(samples,chirps,num_rx*num_tx,numCPI);

for i = 1:numCPI

```
RD_frame = RDC(:,(i-1)*chirps+1:i*chirps,:);

RDMs(:,:,:,i) = fftshift(fft2(RD_frame,N_range,N_Dopp),2);
```

end

% Display the range-Doppler map

figure

imagesc(V,R,20*log10(abs(RDMs(:,:,1,1))/max(max(abs(RDMs(:,:,1,1))))));

colormap(jet(256))

clim = get(gca,'clim');

caxis([clim(1)/2 0])

xlabel('Velocity (m/s)');

ylabel('Range (m)');

%% CA-CFAR

numGuard = 2; % # of guard cells

numTrain = numGuard*2; % # of training cells

P_fa = 1e-5; % desired false alarm rate

SNR_OFFSET = -5; % dB

RDM_dB = 10*log10(abs(RDMs(:,:,1,1))/max(max(abs(RDMs(:,:,1,1)))));

[RDM_mask, cfar_ranges, cfar_dopps, K] = ca_cfar(RDM_dB, numGuard, numTrain, P_fa, SNR_OFFSET);

figure

h=imagesc(V,R,RDM_mask);

xlabel('Velocity (m/s)')

ylabel('Range (m)')

title('CA-CFAR')

%% Perform angular FFT to calculate the angles

rangeFFT = fft(RDC,N_range,1);

angleFFT = fftshift(fft(rangeFFT,N_azimuth,3),3);

range_az = squeeze(sum(angleFFT,2)); % range-azimuth map

doas = zeros(K,181); % direction of arrivals

figure

hold on; grid on;

for i = 1:K

```
doas(i,:) = fftshift(fft(rangeFFT(cfar_ranges(i),cfar_dopps(i),:),181));

plot(ang_ax,10*log10(abs(doas(i,:))))
```

end

xlabel('Azimuth Angle')

ylabel('dB')

Comment: Your code formatting is horribly broken, probably a copy-paste problem. Please fix it.